# emoji not being displayed, weird characters instead

Tags: ios, ascii, core-text, emoji

I'm trying to display an emoji (ascii #55357) in `CoreText` and this is what I'm getting:

[image]

It displays two of these characters and inserts the cursor in the middle. I'm not going to include my `CoreText` code because it's such a mess and I have no idea where the bug is originating from, but what I was just curious has anyone else seen the same problem before in any facet of iOS and what is the meaning of these sort of A in a black and white box characters that got displayed? Does it mean invalid character or something? Just looking for some hints on how to even approach this problem.

Comment: Post the relevant code. Can't help if you don't show what you are doing.

Comment: Are you using substrings at all? Meaning are you taking a portion of a long string and drawing that substring?

Comment: @rmaddy - I definitely will if I figure out what I need to post.

Comment: @moby - Nah, no substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't realize an emoji character has a length of 2 and not 1 like most other characters. So what specifically was causing the issue was I was applying attributes to the emoji when adding it to my NSMutableAttributedString over a length 1 instead of 2. When I changed it to 2 it fixed it:

```
[self.text addAttributes: attributes range:NSMakeRange(self.cursor.position, 2 /* not 1 */)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the tip that emoji characters have a length of 2 helped me figure out my issue.

Comment: @nathan.f77 no prob, this one plagued me for quite a while so glad to help