# Uploaded a site, I see squares with a cross randomly in text

Tags: android, sublimetext

Used Sublime to create code. I uploaded the site and I see randomly squares with crosses in them.

[screenshot of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48MTP.jpg)

On my Mac and iPhone I don't see them. On a Samsung and Huawei phone I do.

I don't see anything rare in my code. I made a screenshot of the part that you see in the first screenshot.

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugiY7.png)

Has someone any idea how I can get this right?

Comment: don't post screenshots of code, insert it as plain text. You have code button in SO editor.

Answer (score 0):

Check device dependent characters(like emoji.) and fonts.
Some characters are shown as blocks.

Maybe related questions
[emoji not being displayed, weird characters instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745653/emoji-not-being-displayed-weird-characters-instead)

[Emoji Support for iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135751/emoji-support-for-ios-and-android)

---

(iPhone or mac can display them, so maybe not for this question but)
if it is language specific character related problem, there are similar questions.

[How can I use special characters in angular directives attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894398/how-can-i-use-special-characters-in-angular-directives-attributes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How can I properly display German characters in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423693/how-can-i-properly-display-german-characters-in-html)